# How to recover the IP of a site with a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ip, firefox-addon, cdn

my problem is for a Firefox extension. I can't find a way to retrieve the IP address of the website loaded on a page in Firefox. However, the data exists:

[Network Monitor ⇾ Header ⇾ Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mI2v.png)

I have seen solutions with dns.resolve or through external websites, but it is not reliable in case of CDN as with Google for example.

I hope you can help me.

Edit:
Up, solution to get the header of the request in JavaScript ?

Comment: What do you mean with _"it is not reliable"_? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is possible in the case of a CDN that between the loading of the page and the DNS request made by the client that the ip changes. This is even more likely in the case where the request is made by an external site.

Comment: I think it's impossible the get the IP address of the currently loaded website. I dons't think this information is passed to the JavaScript engine and I don't know any API that would help here. Theoretically the IP address can change for each request. Maybe there is a way to access more details with extensions but I don't know of anything in this direction.